# Not able to use Robocopy with the folders with Special Characters in the name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy, powershell-cmdlet

I am using robocopy for transferring the data from my local machine to my server. I am facing a problem when the folder name contains a special character in the name of the folder. This is the code snippet I am using for robocopy.

```
robocopy Logs \\1*.***.***.**\Desktop\Test&Pass\Logs\GC /e /Z /sec /mov
```

When I run this command in cmd following is the error that I get:

```
Source : C:\Users\Desktop\Logs\
Dest : \\1*.***.***.**\Desktop\Test\
```

**The system cannot find the path specified.**

The problem here is that the file that I wanna send is named "Test&Pass" but it is only considering "Test".

Looks like cmd is not accepting anything after the special character "&".

Can someone suggest any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Use doublequotes!, _(and preferably the full paths too)_ `@"%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Logs" "\\1*.***.***.**\%UserName%\Desktop\Test&Pass\Logs\GC" /<Options>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I tried your method, the cmd is not throwing any error, even the robocopy is showing 100% complete, but the file is not getting transfered in the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Key takeaways: chcp 1252, ANSI

I dont know is this relevant in here, but:
In my case:
I want to copy folders with special characters in their names, like: á,é,ó,ő,ö,ű.
My solution was this: I wrote this in the first line of the batch: chcp 1252
This changed the code page to windows-1252, after for the actual robocopy job source and destination in double qoutes "" and after I  was saved the whole batch in ANSI format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).